# I can't click a button because of overlapping padding

Tags: html, css

I am making tooltip using `antd` library. I needed to override some styles and now I have a problem.

I can't click on children because of overlapping padding of tooltip. I tried set z-index but it does not helps

I do not think pasting the code is a good idea because `antd` library add some extra styles and my code will not be reliable enough

Here is link to codesandbox: Try to click on button.

https://codesandbox.io/s/colorful-tooltip-antd-4-21-0-forked-0g7we8?file=/Tooltip.js

Question:
How should I style this children to be able to click on it

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to increase the z-index, your button will be able to be clicked after it increases like so:

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}
button {
  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Comment: okey, but children can be anything other than a button. I can't add this to Children created with styled components?

Answer (score 1):

There's padding-bottom being set to the tooltip by the `.ant-tooltip-placement-top` class. Add that class to your tooltip.js so you can override it and set the padding-bottom to 0px and you won't have to worry about it.

`.ant-tooltip-placement-top { padding-bottom: 0; }`

[image]

Comment: I added class .ant-tooltip-placement-top and set padding: 0, then I set z-index for children and it still does not help

Comment: @Acuriousstudent Can you link a codesandbox? Are you and the OP having the same issue? What does "does not help" mean? Are you unable to click the button?